# Trigger a JavaScript function based on the data fetched from Woo commerce hook

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, javascript, hooks

I have read quite a lot of possible ways to do it but after going through each of them I'm still not able to understand what should be the correct way of doing it and how the correct way works. 
**Question:**
When the woo-commerce add to cart hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart` is triggered I want to send the recently added product data (and also user data) from a javascript function to an analytics data collector tool (through analytics.io in this case).
**Problem in implementation:**
The hooks such as `wp_head` `wp_footer` are able to run javascript code inside of them either by `wp_localize_script` or `echo <script>//some js code</script>`. Whereas the woocommerce hooks such as `woocommerce_add_to_cart` can't run javascript code inside them. As per my understanding this is due the fact that `woocommerce_add_to_cart` update is happening via ajax.

**What I've tried till now:**
One possible solution I found was when the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook is triggered change the data attribute of the **Add to cart** button and then read them in the jQuery script via `added_to_cart` event. For reference, I implemented this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780949/get-specific-woocommerce-product-data-on-added-to-cart-javascript-event and this works.

**What I want:**

> I want to update/create a javascript object when the woocommerce hook is triggered and then send that data via a javascript function to the analytics tool. Is adding data attributes to the button/HTML element a good way to do this task?

P.S- I'm new to the WordPress/Php ecosystem and would really appreciate it if someone can explain a possible solution to my question in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot of articles and solutions I finally figured it out:

Directory Structure for the plugin ([Boilerplate directory structure used from here](https://wppb.me/))

First step:
Register a `js` script which would track the event/ user activity and pass it the ajax URL through which it would fetch the product details via ajax.

```
// admin/class-pluginname-admin.php or public/class-pluginname-public.php

function register_my_scripts(){
wp_register_script('script_alias', ...);
wp_localize_script('script_alias', 'localParams', array('ajax_url'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
wp_enqueue_script('script_alias');
}
```

Second:
Create a `js` file which would make an ajax call when the trigger occurs.

```
// event-js-file.js
...

$.ajax({
url: localParams.ajax_url,
type: "POST",
data:{
action: "my_custom_action", // calling the custom ajax action
// send data via this post request
},
success: function(res){// success response of the request},
error: function(err){// error as response of the request}
});
```

Third:
Create a custom ajax action which would respond to the request made via the js file and give the required data.

```
// includes/class-pluginname.php

add_action('wp_ajax_my_custom_action', 'my_custom_function', priority_value);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_action', 'my_custom_function', priority_value);
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_scripts', priority_value);

// admin/class-pluginname-admin.php or public/class-pluginname-public.php

function my_custom_function(){
// This is called via the js file ajax call.
// Calculate or generate or resolve the data necessary and send the 
// response to the js script.
}
```